# не отображается библиотека к проекту C#

Tags: c#

Возникла проблема, не могу подключить библиотеку к своему проекту. В ссылках проекта она не появляется.

1. В файле `********.csproj` прописано все как надо

   ```
   <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
      <Reference Include="TradeMatic">
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Tradematic LLC\Tradematic Trader\TradeMatic.dll</HintPath>
   </Reference>
   </ItemGroup>
   <ItemGroup>
   ```
2. В обозревателе объектов эту библиотеку могу просмотреть.
   Атрибуты:

   ```
   [System.Reflection.AssemblyTrademarkAttribute(""),
   System.Reflection.AssemblyCopyrightAttribute("Copyright © 2009-2018, TradeMatic LLC"),
   System.Reflection.AssemblyProductAttribute("Tradematic Trader"),
   System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisibleAttribute(false),
   System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute(".NETFramework,Version=v4.6", FrameworkDisplayName = ".NET Framework 4.6"),
   System.Reflection.AssemblyFileVersionAttribute("1.9.4.3"),
   System.Runtime.InteropServices.GuidAttribute("4ea6bd0c-8abc-433f-8d1d-be0a8001ed24"),
   System.Diagnostics.DebuggableAttribute(2),
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeCompatibilityAttribute(WrapNonExceptionThrows = true),
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilationRelaxationsAttribute(8),
   System.Reflection.AssemblyTitleAttribute("Tradematic"),
   System.Reflection.AssemblyCompanyAttribute("Tradematic LLC"),
   System.Reflection.AssemblyConfigurationAttribute(""),
   System.Reflection.AssemblyDescriptionAttribute("")]
   ```
3. Версию проекта устанавливал на `Version=v4.6`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы подключаете библиотеки руками через .csproj?

Comment: Где она не отображается?

Comment: нет, я подключаю через visual studio, по команде добавить ссылку...

Comment: Стандартная ссылка при создании библиотеки классов

Comment: Добавил картинку для наглядности

Comment: как я понимаю, из этой библиотеки наследуемый класс Script. что говорит VS по правой кнопке на Script? Есть что-то в стиле "add reference"? Возможно, там другой namespace

Comment: Предлагает создать свой класс, или поменять Script на другой класс

Comment: при попытке выполнить сборку вот такая ошибка: Серьезность Код Описание Проект Файл Строка Состояние подавления
Ошибка CS0009 Не удалось открыть файл метаданных "C:\Program Files (x86)\Tradematic LLC\Tradematic Trader\TradeMatic.dll" — Illegal tables in compressed metadata stream. TradeMaticAlexShape D:\S#\Programmingrobots\TradeMaticAlexShape\TradeMaticAlexShape\CSC 1 Активно

Comment: такое ощущение, что проблема не в вашем подключении библиотеки, а в самой библиотеке. Вы уверены, что она корректна?

Comment: не могу точно сказать, написал разработчикам, жду...

Comment: Подчёркивает красным - решение стандартное: выйти-войти. Ну то есть перезапустить Студию (или выгрузить-загрузить проект). Бывает такое почему-то.

Comment: @АлексейСемёнов разработчики ответили?

Comment: нет пока что, не ответити

Answer (score 0):

Проблема с подключением библиотеки  к проекту связана с системой защиты этой библиотеки. (ответ разработчиков)

Answer (score 0):

В новой версии 1.9.4.4 добавим возможность связки Tradematic и Visual Studio.

Приносим свои извинения за неудобства.